# Some settings in 50-synaptics.conf have no effect

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome, touchpad

I am having trouble with editing the synaptics file for my touchpad, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`. I got Debian-based Linux with Gnome 3.4.2.

The relevant portion (I suppose) of said file goes as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad catchall"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "MaxSpeed" "4"
Option "AccelFactor" "0.0825"
Option "ClickPad" "1"
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
```

What is interesting is that some of these settings are obeyed, while others are ignored. It appears that the `AccelFactor` is obeyed, yet `VertTwoFingerScroll` is certainly ignored. I tweaked the former, restarted, and saw the actual difference under `synclient -l`.

By the way, I checked this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26290/50-synaptics-conf-options-not-working
And I can confirm I have no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, only `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`.

I reviewed the Debian-wiki for Synaptics and it may be that something else is overriding these. I can elaborate. Otherwise it could be something else. But I prefer to get the community's feedback before venturing further.

I had Debian-based Linux for 4-6 weeks now and am in the early stages of the learning. My main goal is to tweak this as soon as possible, to get onto another routine for learning besides looking into immediate items.

My constraints are time and ignorance. I prefer few steps over many in any solution, and GUI over CLI, so that I can continue my learning in a different order than that dictated just by problem-fixing. But in this case it seems that a simpler correction of some settings file should do.

Comment: I suspect that the settings are not ignored, but overridden by some program that runs later, perhaps as part of Gnome. Have you checked what settings Gnome has to offer?

Comment: From what I recall, these settings are not as extensive in the touchpad GUI configuration offered by Gnome. I do agree overriding is happening. The question is where to identify the file with the sequencing of settings. Hoping to save research time.

Comment: Does `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1` works?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is when added to the text file above that it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you encounter is the overriding of your configuration by the GNOME environment.

I suggest you to install dconf-editor if it is not already installed

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then run it in your terminal with you own user (without using sudo), a gui should open. Go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse and deactivate the **active** option. Log out and log in, it should work.

By doing so you ask your Desktop Environment to NOT override the configuration for your mouse.

Is is possible to do everything in the terminal by using gsettings like this :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
```

gsettings is very powerful but must be use with cautious. It is useful to use it when you're looking for a specific key, for instance with:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep mouse
```

I advice you to first copy the actual settings that you are using just in case new problems show up (this is always a good practice) by doing :

```
synclient >> touchpad_original_config
```

You will be able to retrieve your current values for the options afterward.

If it doesn't work, share with us the content of the last Xorg.X.log file in /var/log to give us more information about your issue.

source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#GNOME.2FCinnamon

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false` fixed the touchpad behavior in my XPS 13 9350

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Option "ClickPad" "0"

Don't know why but on my computer I can't two-finger-scroll with it enabled; disabled I can.